# Реализация продажи виртуальных товаров из приложения Android - есть ли библиотеки?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, монетизация, поиск-библиотек

Как организовать продажу виртуальных товаров из приложения?

Интересует не столько код, сколько сам принцип. Есть ли у плэй-маркета специальная библиотека для этого, или надо самому как-то с операторами сотовой связи и банками контакты налаживать?

Comment: вопрос из ряда "погугли за меня"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да, библиотека есть - **Google Play Billing Library**.
2. Всё идёт через гугл. Процесс покупок аналогичен покупке приложений. В приложении просто (вроде) диалог появляется с предложением списать деньги с привязанного счёта/карты/симкарты. Гугл за услуги забирает 30%.
3. Вот ссылка на [доки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)